# Swift BLAS cblas_cgemv complex numbers

Tags: swift, complex-numbers, blas

I have been able to use cblas_sgemv where all values are real. However I cannot use cblas_cgemv without getting an 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' error. For this function am I right in assuming that the complex part comes directly after the real part in the array that the function takes as an argument? For example if I had a matrix:

```
1 + 2i, 3 + 4i
5 + 6i, 7 + 8i
```

then it would be represented as [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0].
Also for any given matrix and vector what values should N, M, lda, incX and incY with respect to its representation in the array?

Full Example:
For cblas_sgemv where function prototype is:

```
func cblas_sgemv(_ __Order: CBLAS_ORDER, _ __TransA: CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, _ __M: Int32, _ __N: Int32, _ __alpha: Float, _ __A: UnsafePointer<Float>, _ __lda: Int32, _ __X: UnsafePointer<Float>, _ __incX: Int32, _ __beta: Float, _ __Y: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, _ __incY: Int32)
```

This code works:

```
let matrix: [Float] = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
let vector: [Float] = [1.0,2.0]
let matrixConverted: UnsafePointer<Float> = UnsafePointer<Float>(matrix)
let vectorConverted: UnsafePointer<Float> = UnsafePointer<Float>(vector)
let matrixSize = sqrt(Double(matrix.count)
let total: [Float] = [Float](count: Int(matrixSize), repeatedValue: 0.0)
let totalConverted: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(total)
cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, Int32(matrixSize), Int32(matrixSize), 1.0, matrixConverted, Int32(matrixSize), vectorConverted, 1, 0, totalConverted, 1)
```

The answer is stored in total. So what would it look like to do the same but with the complex matrix above and the function cblas_cgemv with prototype:

```
func cblas_cgemv(_ __Order: CBLAS_ORDER, _ __TransA: CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, _ __M: Int32, _ __N: Int32, _ __alpha: UnsafePointer<Void>, _ __A: UnsafePointer<Void>, _ __lda: Int32, _ __X: UnsafePointer<Void>, _ __incX: Int32, _ __beta: UnsafePointer<Void>, _ __Y: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, _ __incY: Int32)
```

More information and reference can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000414-SW55

Comment: A (minimal) *self-contained* example with *actual code* demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Example given which works for real values only. I am looking to do the same calculation but when complex numbers are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your existing code is a bit too complicated and has an error:

- The input matrix and vector can be passed directly to the `cblas_sgemv()`
  function, `matrixConverted` and `vectorConverted` are not needed.
- Creating a *mutable* pointer to the *constant* array `total` is
  not allowed. The result vector must be variable (and the 
  `totalConverted` is also not needed).

So your code can be simplified to:

```
let matrix: [Float] = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
let vector: [Float] = [1.0,2.0]

let matrixSize = sqrt(Double(matrix.count))
var total = [Float](count: Int(matrixSize), repeatedValue: 0.0)

cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, Int32(matrixSize), Int32(matrixSize), 1.0, matrix, Int32(matrixSize), vector, 1, 0, &total, 1)
```

---

The layout of *complex* numbers in the BLAS routines is documented
in `<cblas.h>`:

```
 * A note on complex data layouts:
 *
 * In order to allow straightforward interoperation with other libraries and
 * complex types in C and C++, complex data in BLAS is passed through an opaque
 * pointer (void *).  The layout requirements on this complex data are that
 * the real and imaginary parts are stored consecutively in memory, and have
 * the alignment of the corresponding real type (float or double).  The BLAS
 * complex interfaces are compatible with the following types:
 *
 *     - The C complex types, defined in <complex.h>.
 *     - The C++ std::complex types, defined in <complex>.
 *     - The LAPACK complex types, defined in <Accelerate/vecLib/clapack.h>.
 *     - The vDSP types DSPComplex and DSPDoubleComplex, defined in <Accelerate/vecLib/vDSP.h>.
 *     - An array of size two of the corresponding real type.
 *     - A structure containing two elements, each of the corresponding real type.
```

Therefore, to multiply

```
| 1 + 2i  3 + 4i |    | 1 + 2i |
|                |  * |        |
| 5 + 6i  7 + 8i |    | 3 + 4i |
```

you can represent each complex number as two floating
point numbers, stored consecutively:

```
let matrix: [Float] = [1.0,2.0, 3.0,4.0, 5.0,6.0, 7.0,8.0]
let vector: [Float] = [1.0,2.0, 3.0,4.0]

let matrixSize = sqrt(Double(matrix.count/2))
var total = [Float](count: vector.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)

let alpha : [Float] = [1.0, 0.0]
let beta : [Float] = [1.0, 0.0]

cblas_cgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, Int32(matrixSize), Int32(matrixSize), beta, matrix, Int32(matrixSize), vector, 1, alpha, &total, 1)
```

Or you can represent the complex numbers using the `DSPComplex`,
`COMPLEX`, or `__CLPK_complex` structure (which all have the
same layout):

```
let matrix = [DSPComplex(real: 1.0, imag: 2.0), DSPComplex(real: 3.0, imag: 4.0),
              DSPComplex(real: 5.0, imag: 6.0), DSPComplex(real: 7.0, imag: 8.0)]

let vector = [DSPComplex(real: 1.0, imag: 2.0), DSPComplex(real: 3.0, imag: 4.0)]

let matrixSize = sqrt(Double(matrix.count))
var total  =  [DSPComplex](count: Int(matrixSize), repeatedValue: DSPComplex())

var alpha = [DSPComplex(real: 1.0, imag: 0.0)]
var beta  = [DSPComplex(real: 1.0, imag: 0.0)]

cblas_cgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, Int32(matrixSize), Int32(matrixSize), alpha, matrix, Int32(matrixSize), vector, 1, beta, &total, 1)
```

In either case, the dimensions `M`, `N` etc refer to the count of complex numbers, so they are identical to the values `M=N=2` in your example
of real numbers, and `alpha` and `beta` are an array as well to
represent a complex factor.

Comment: I will try this approach. Thank you very much for your answer and the simplifications, it is greatly appreciated.